# Logging GC events in Ruby

Tags: ruby, debugging, garbage-collection

I'm trying to debug my c extension (https://github.com/rgeo/rgeo), and am currently improving handling of compaction ([a nice video introducing that topic](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H8iWLoarTZc)), and I'd like to have informations about when the GC is running.

So far I found one solutions to see how many times the GC has run:

```rb
GC::Profiler.enable
at_exit { GC::Profiler.report }
```

However I'd rather gather information when the GC runs directly, not by waiting for the end of my program.

I found that [`gc.c`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v3_1_0/gc.c) has a [`gc_report` method that would do the trick](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/fb4df44d1670e9d25aef6b235a7281199a177edb/gc.c#L8925), however it looks like I have to recompile ruby to work with that one.

Isn't there a simple way to enable GC events reporting? Note that I'm using rbenv on a macos, if that may help.